# i want to Retrieve data from Django API and store it in database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I am new to  django restframework. `GET` request works fine, the data from database is retrived on client side, but while doing the post request no data is added to database. I want to retrieve the data from react axios from django api and store it in database. It is not showing any error but it is also not adding the json data in database.
here is views.py

```
class formAPI(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        if request.method=='GET':
            formData=Form.objects.all()
            serializer=FormSerializer(formData,many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        
    def post(self,request):
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            data_Serializer = FormSerializer(data=request.data)
            if data_Serializer.is_valid():
                data_Serializer.save()
                return Response(data_Serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({'key': 'value'})
```

here is models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# Create your models here.
class Form(models.Model):
    Province=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    District=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    PalikaType=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    PalikaName=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Ward_No=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Ward_Office_Address=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Ward_Contact_No=PhoneNumberField()
    X_Cords=models.FloatField(null=False)   
    Y_Cords=models.FloatField(null=False)
    Chairperson_Name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Chaiperson_Contact_No=PhoneNumberField()
    Secretary_Name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Secretary_Contact_No=PhoneNumberField()
    Area=models.FloatField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Total_Households=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    Total_Population=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    Total_Male_Population=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    Total_Female_Population=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    Website= models.URLField(max_length=200)
    Email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    location= models.PointField(srid=4326,null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'PalikaName: %s' % self.name
```

here is the data to be stored

```
{   Province: "province 1",
        District: "bhaktapur",
        PalikaType: "gaupalika",
        PalikaName: "madhyapur gaupalika",
        Ward_No: "5",
        Ward_Office_Address: "balkumari",
        Ward_Contact_No: "+9779818523950",
        X_Cords: 85.385252,
        Y_Cords: 27.675952,
        Chairperson_Name: "kumar sanu",
        Chaiperson_Contact_No: "+9779815523950",
        Secretary_Name: "ranja",
        Secretary_Contact_No: "+9779813523950",
        Area: 784.0,
        Total_Households: 422,
        Total_Population: 32,
    Total_Male_Population: 224,
    Total_Female_Population: 124,
        Website: "http://madhyapurthimimun.gov.np/en",
        Email: "info@madhyapurthimimun.gov.np",
        
    }
```

here is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include                 # add this
from rest_framework import routers                    # add this
from formback import views 
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns 

router = routers.DefaultRouter()                      # add this
router.register(r'form', views.FormView, 'Form')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^getform/', views.formAPI.as_view()),
]
```

here is serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Form

class FormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = '__all__'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check if the data_serializer. is_valid() is True or False? add a print statement to check that and maybe change`return Response({'key': 'value'})` to `return Response(data_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)` just to see  which status code you receive and the error in case of a 400. Does this help to identify the issue?

Comment: Also don't use `request.method == 'POST'` if you are using class based views, since you are already defining `get` and `post` method. Probably there is some error with your serializer that's why it is not being saved. You can print `data_serializer.errors` as mentioned above.

Comment: If you add an else block to `if data_Serializer.is_valid():` and print `data_Serializer.errors`, you may get that you `location` key is missing in your `json`.